# Can the same SD card be used for Raspberry Pi Zero and Raspberry Pi 3A+ that is to be accessed wirelessly (SSH & wpa_supplicant)?

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, sd-card, raspbian-stretch, pi-zero

I wanted to use an older Raspbian 9 (Stretch) version of 2017/2018 because I wanted to use the "perf" tool which is not available for the current version.

But the previous version was not able to boot by Raspberry Pi 3A+ (no green / ACT light on Raspberry Pi 3A+).

Hence I inserted that SD card in Raspberry Pi Zero and ran commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel
```

Then after that I removed that SD card and inserted in my Raspberry Pi 3A+. The green light was attained successfully, but then my Raspberry Pi 3A+ was not able to connect to my Wi-Fi router.

I again copied/inserted ssh (without any extension) and wpa_supplicant.conf file in the SD card; and re-inserted it into the Raspberry Pi 3A+, but still I couldn't make it connect to my Wi-Fi router.

What could be possibly wrong in my procedure?

Comment: Have you set the country code in `wpa_supplicant.conf`? What is this `perf` tool that apparently isn't available in buster?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I did set the country code in supplicant file. perf is a performance analysing tool which is available just for a very few kernel versions. I did try to make it work for the latest versions, but it won't.